# Creating a video from a sequence of images in Matlab

Tags: video, matlab

I am stuck on how to create an video file from from a sequence of images.

I have a folder with images as follows:

```
image01.png 
image02.png 
... 
image150.png
```

How do I combine them to a video in Matlab?

I saw this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/convert-between-image-sequences-and-video.html#ImagesAndVideoExample-5) explaining it, but I could not understand it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to do something like this:

```
nImage = 150;                                                        % L1
fps = 3.0;                                                           % L2
addToInFolder = 'Address\to\Input\Images\Folder';                    % L3
addToOutFolder = 'Address\to\Output\Video\Folder';                   % L4

oVideo = VideoWriter(fullfile(addToOutFolder, 'myVideo.avi'));       % L5
oVideo.FrameRate = fps;                                              % L6
open(oVideo)                                                         % L7
for i = 1:nImage                                                     % L8
    fname = ['image' num2str(i, '%.2d') '.png'];                     % L9
    curImage = imread(fullfile(addToInFolder,fname));                % L10
    writeVideo(oVideo, curImage);                                    % L11
end                                                                  % L12
close(oVideo)                                                        % L13
```

Since you could not follow the example, here is a break down of what is going on per line:

- L1 => Total number of images which based on your file names is 150
- L2 => Frame per second of the movie you are making
- L3 => Address to the input folder of your images
- L4 => Address to the output folder for your movie
- L5 => Create a complete address to the output movie (.avi) file and make a video file at this address to be written
- L6 => Set frame rate of the movie to `fps`. `FrameRate` is a property of a video object. See [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) for the complete list of properties you can play with. There are properties you may want to play with like `Quality`, `Duration`, `CompressionRatio`, etc).
- L7 => Video file needs to be opened to allow for writing data, otherwise you do not have the permission to write to this file
- L8 => Let's begin a loop over each image and make a frame out of it
- L9 => Create a string of file name for the current image (image01.png, ...., image150.png)
- L10 => Read the png file and store its data in variable `curImage`
- L11 => Add contents of `curImage` to the video file pointed by `oVideo`
- L13 => Don't forget to close the video file (`oVideo`) that was opened before